# CSV file containing column with occasional comma in parentheses crashes pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to write a function that parses a very large .csv file. Unfortunately, whoever made the csv file did not use a very good delimiter as one of the text columns occasionally uses the delimiter (I have no control over this). The csv file does not have quotes surrounding the text i.e. a problematic row would look like this:

```
colAVal, (colBVal_1, colBVal_2), colCVal
```

I should note that for all of the problematic rows, the value of column B is standard in that it is always `(colBVal_1, colBVal_2)`

Because most rows do not have this issue, pandas.read_csv expects 3 columns and crashes when it hits one of these problematic rows.

Because the comma is in parentheses, I cannot figure out a way to solve this use the quotechar parameter in read_csv. I would like to avoid writing my own read_csv function to go line by line and manually account for this issue if possible. Ideally, I am looking for a way to tell read_csv that when it encounters (colBVal_1, colBVal_2), it should automatically assign it to colB or have read_csv break the data into 2 dataframes: one with 3 columns and one with 4 that I can manually merge together.

Comment: Your best bet would be to write a parser on your own and feed the resulting structure into pandas.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, you could formulate a grammar with your "broken" csv lines and feed the resulting output to a `pandas` DataFrame.
The following can surely be optimized but might give you an idea:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor
import pandas as pd

broken_garbage = """
1, (2, 3), 4
colAVal, (colBVal_1, colBVal_2), colCVal,
this, one, right
234,(123,456),789
"""

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    content     = garbage? line+
    line        = entry+ newline?
    entry       = value sep?
    value       = word / (lpar word sep word rpar)

    lpar        = "("
    rpar        = ")"
    word        = ~"\w+"
    sep         = ws? "," ws?

    ws          = ~"[\t ]+"
    newline     = ~"[\r\n]+"
    garbage     = (ws / newline)+
    """
)

class BrokenVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_value(self, node, visited_children):
        child = visited_children[0]
        if isinstance(child, list):
            _, value1, _, value2, _ = child
            return (value1.text, value2.text)
        else:
            return child.text

    def visit_entry(self, node, visited_children):
        values, _ = visited_children
        return values

    def visit_line(self, node, visited_children):
        content = visited_children[0]
        return [item for item in content]

    def visit_content(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children[1]

tree = grammar.parse(broken_garbage)

broken = BrokenVisitor()
values = broken.visit(tree)

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=["one", "two", "three"])
print(df)
```

---

This yields

```
       one                     two    three
0        1                  (2, 3)        4
1  colAVal  (colBVal_1, colBVal_2)  colCVal
2     this                     one    right
3      234              (123, 456)      789
```

---

Look at the grammar which reflects your structure. The `BrokenVisitor` class visits each of the grammar bricks and returns the lines as a list. This result is then fed into the `pandas.DataFrame` constructor.

---

---

Alternatively you could use the newer [`regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) which supports `\K` and replace all the commas in brackets with another character:

```
\([^,()]+\K,
```

In `Python` this could be:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.sub(r'\([^,()]+\K,')
new_string = rx.sub('@', old_string)
```

Afterwards, you can feed the new string into `pandas.read_csv()` directly.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Lb66wK/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any example data it's hard to know what is needed, but:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def my_parser(csv_file)
    with open(csv_file, "r") as fh:
        for line in fh:
            line = line.strip()

            if re.match(r".*\(.*,.*\).*", line):
                # Process line with extra commas
                # ...
            else:
                # Process normal line
                # ...

            yield processed_line


df = pd.Dataframe(my_parser("file.csv"), ...)
```

For the processing, you could try to replace only the commas that are in parenthesises with another character.

I would recommend using a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) as the structure to hold your `processed_line` as they have fields that are automatically used by `pandas` as the Series names; though you will have to do some type checking or specifying, as pandas will treat all entries as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion to just search and replace. That worked pretty well. Added code below for reference in case anyone else runs into this type of issue.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
text = open('file/location', "r")
        text = StringIO(''.join([i for i in text]) \
            .replace("(colBVal_1, colBVal_2)", "(colBVal_1 colBVal_2)"))
        df= pd.read_csv( text )
```

Comment: Please look into https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work